# Web application authentication for Linux accounts

Tags: linux, authentication, web

I have a web application which has a user authentication system. For the application I am building, I need the users to log-in to a linux box. I was wondering whether there is way I can configure linux to use the web app auth backend instead of referring to /etc/passwd.